# VB.NET Simultaneous connections LocalDB Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, localdb

I've been using some LocalDB databases (.mdf files). I've been the only one using those DB for a while, but more and more are using it now. Every time we use the app at the same time we have an error because we connect to the DB at the same time.

Is there a way to allow simultaneous connections to an SQL LocalDB database?
If not what is the best alternative assuming we will never have more than 5 people connecting at the same time?

Here is the code i'm suing to acess my DB file :

```
Public Shared Function SQLQuery(query As String, connectionString As String, tableName As String)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cm)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adp.Fill(ds, tableName)
    adp.Dispose()
    cm.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
    SQLQuery = ds
End Function
```

And here is an example of connection string :

```
Public Shared connectionStringScreenDataDB As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='P:\Clement\Visual Studio\PanoramaFund2App\PanoramaFund2App\ScreenDataDB.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: "C# VB" in the title...which one is it?

Comment: It's VB, but I guess it doesn't depend on it ?

Comment: this sounds rather strange.. can you tell us what the errors are sounds like the error is on how you are connecting to the database.. can you show us the code in regards to how you are connecting to the Sql Server DB

Comment: When using LocalDB, by default you cannot have multiple connections to the same instance. Initially LocalDB was supposed to be a single user solution. Now I think it is possible to have a sharing db between multiple users See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx about the share option (beware of the requirements for the user starting the instance)

Comment: Thanks, I just added the code i'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDB allows for unlimited (local) concurrent connections; see [SQL Express v LocalDB v SQL Compact Edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition/)

Your connections string appears to point to a shared drive. LocalDB doesn't accept remote connections. The idea with shared network folder might work (I doubt it though); keep in mind that only one LocalDB instance can have any given database file (and log file) open at the same time.

**Alternatives**: Simplified said, LocalDB's purpose is to be used locally for one application on one machine. If you need remote access you can use SQL Server (not the Express edition) or any other database.

Comment: Thanks, what would be you best recommendation for sharing the database in the office ?

Comment: See update: any other DB such as SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: @Clement Unlike LocalDB, a Microsoft Access database saved on a server share will permit concurrent access. When designed correctly (and if you're not too aggressive) it can be very effective for multiple users, especially with desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an alternative idea. Due to that file being local and multiple users are accessing it. You could always host the database online and then link into the databse that way. which will then allow all of the edits to the database to be instant.