# Unable to access database simultaneously from application and SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database in the App_Data directory of my ASP.NET(C#) application. If I open the database in Sql Server Management Studio I cannot access the database from my application. If I close the SSMS connection and try to access the database from my application it works but then I cannot use the database in SSMS after reconnecting. I have checked that "Restrict Access" option is set to MULTI_USER in Database properties.

EDIT: The error I get in ASP.NET page when SSMS is running is:

Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'ravi-PC\ravi'.

When I close SSMS(I have to close SSMS, disconnecting Object Browser Doesn't Work) access the ASP.NET page the ASP.NET Page works fine.

When I reopen SSMS and try to access the database the error I get is:

Unable to open the physical file "File path" Operating System Error 32: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" (Microsoft SQL Server Error: Error 5120)

**Edit 2** : This question is not a duplicate as I am neither using LocalDB or remote server. I restarted the SQL service and now get a different error. I am able to connect but when trying to access the Tables I get this error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The client driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed.  Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase the number of recovery attempts. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476

---

Cannot open database "C:\USERS\RAVI\SOURCE\WEBSITES\FIRSTTRY\APP_DATA\MYDATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ravi-PC\ravi'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4060)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=4060&LinkId=20476

Comment: Please define "cannot access". What error messages do you get?

Comment: Updated the question with errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# VB Simultaneous connections LocalDB Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022498/c-sharp-vb-simultaneous-connections-localdb-database)

Comment: I checked that question. I am not using LocalDB but SQL Server Express.

Comment: What is the value of `Server-Properties -> Connections -> Max number of concurrent connections`?

Comment: @MatSnow It is 0 (Unlimited)

Comment: Please post your connection string. Based on [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) I suspect you cannot connect to the same mdf twice: (also applies to SQL Express) "When you create a project with these settings and run it, LocalDB attaches the aspnet.mdf file and names the database "aspnet" Then when you create another project and run that one, LocalDB tries to attach that project's aspnet.mdf file to the same database name "aspnet". The operation fails because that name is already attached to the first project's aspnet.mdf file."

Comment: My Connection string is this: "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

If SQL Server one cannot attach to the same mdf file how do I make the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AttachDbFilename` and `User Instance` options are used to spin up a single user instance of SQLExpress, attached to this specific MDF-File.

You wrote that you're not using LocalDB but a "normal" SQLExpress-instance instead.
So the MDF-File is locked, because it's already attached to the SQLExpress-Instance.

To get it working, change the connection string to:

```
"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Comment: It fails with the error: `Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ravinder-PC\ravinder'.` . But I expected it to as the mdf file is in App_Data folder. How to specify that or import this mdf file into the folder that SQL Server serves from by default. (I don't know if that makes sense I come from MySQL background where that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really simple, in Visual Studio I had to find the server in SQL Server Object Explorer from there I got the connection string which works as I wanted to.